# bash: replace block of text

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file

```
# my file
# is here

section1 {
      foo
      nothing important
}
section2 {
      this is important
      this is also important
}
```

I need to replace the first section's contents with other contents:

```
section1 {
      bar
      really important
}
```

I've tried using `sed` regex matching, but it catches the 2nd section ending bracket. How can I do it? Other tools than `sed` are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your regex?

Comment: `{ echo "New section 1"; grep -A999 "section2" originalFile; } > newFile` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty perl file that will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open ( INFILE, 'document.txt' ) || die "Cannot read input file.";
open ( OUTFILE, '>document2.txt' ) || die "Cannot write output file.";

$replaced = "0";

while ( $line_in = <INFILE> ) {
    print OUTFILE $line_in;
    next unless $line_in =~ /^\s*section1 {\s*$/ && $replaced eq "0";
        print OUTFILE "      bar\n";
        print OUTFILE "      really important\n";
        while ( $line_in = <INFILE> ) {
            next unless $line_in =~ /^\s*}\s*$/;
                print OUTFILE $line_in;
                $replaced = "1";
                last;
        }
}

close ( INFILE );
close ( OUTFILE );
```

It does leave the original file alone and give you a second file with the edits, rather than editing the original file in place, but it's more of an example of basic principles to get you started.